# Is there an easy way to convert autocad polygons to adobe swf format?

Tags: flash, autocad, dwg

I am looking for a easy way to convert Autocad polygons to swf files. Is there a converter for that? Or is there an intermediatory format that can be used to convert from polygons to the adobe flash swfs. Each polygon would be a swf file.

Comment: This sounds like it should be in SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer would be 'not really' at the moment.

I found this interesting blog entry about a [Flex/Flash AutoCAD DWG/DXF Viewer](http://labs.zavoo.com/?p=34),
and the comments explain the project approach better.

Also, [Autodesk Butterfly](http://butterfly.autodesk.com/) looks great, maybe it can be handy.

Another thought would be converting 2d plan views to SVG and using an [as3 svg render library](http://code.google.com/p/as3svgrendererlib/).

Update:
The the as3 svg render library is the developer friendly version.

You can use Illustrator as intermediary tool as it imports AutoCAD plan views and export Flash(SWF)

Here's a tutorial I've put together:

1. **Open** up the **AutoCAD file** in **Illustrator**
2. **Select the Layer** that nests all the shapes:

[image: dwg to swf 1]

3. In the Layer's palette select **Release To Layers(Sequence)**

[image: dwg to swf 2]

4. Go to **File > Export >** choose **Flash** as the output format
5. In the **SWF Options** you can select **AI Layers to SWF Files**
   if that is what you need. You can also export to symbols, single file, etc.

[image: dwg to swf 3]

You can even export animation as swf from Illustrator. Say you have a lathe/revolve or extrusion: you can duplicate it, modify the duplicate's properties, make a blend, release to layers then export the layers as SWF frames :)

HTH,
George

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The suggestions are still not very clear. I am still a bit lost. Right now, my solution is to grab each Autocad polygon, save it as its own Autocad file and use the export function to export each polygon as a swf file, one by one...

Comment: @hip10 I thought you need a code only version, I've updated my answer, although it's starting to look like superuser material :)

Answer (score 0):

A "swf" file is not a 3d format per se, therefore "converting autocad polygons to adobe swf format" is ill formed

Comment: Sorry, I mean convert the polygon to a 2d format. AutoCAD has a 2d view.